# Change a 1500 column data-set for easier front-end manipulation

Tags: mongodb, data-visualization, database

I have a [data-set that consist of 1500 columns and 6500 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbK1b.png) and I am trying to figure out what the best way is to shape the data for web based user interactive visualizations.

What I am trying to do is make the data more interactive and create an admin console that allows anyone to filter the data visually. 
Front-end could potentially be based on Crossfilter, D3 and DC.js and give the user basically end-less filtering possibilities(date, value, country. In addition there will be some pre defined views like top and bottom 10 values.

I have seen  and tested some great examples [like this one](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2015/01/interactive-data-visualization-d3-dc-python-mongodb/), but after testing it did not really fit for the large amount of columns I had and it was based on a full JSON dump from the MongoDB. This amounted in very long loading times and loss of full interactivity with the data.

So in the end my question is what is the best approach (starting with normalization) in getting the data shaped in the right way so it can be manipulated from a front-end. Changing the amount of columns is a priority.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the piece of data that you shared suggests that the dataset is highly denormalized. To allow for querying and visualization from a database backend I would suggest normalizing. This is no small bit software work but in the end you will have relational data which is much easier to deal with.

It's hard to guess where you would start but from the bit of data you showed there would be a country table, an event table of some sort and probably some tables of enumerated values.

In any case you will have a hard time finding a db engine that a lows that many columns. The row count is not a problem. I think in the end you will want a db with dozens of tables.